# Run installed python packages from the command line

Tags: python, macos, bash

I have installed some command line clients using `pip` that should run straight from the command line without the python keyword and using the path to the file.

For instance [`shub` from scrapinghub](http://doc.scrapinghub.com/shub.html) or [turbolift](https://github.com/cloudnull/turbolift)

All I get is:

`shub: command not found`

and

`turbolift: command not found`

What environment variables should I add to .bash_profile to enable the desired command line behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory which contains the script you want to run must be added to your `PATH`.

For example, to add `$HOME/bin/pip/`, you would use

```
PATH=$HOME/bin/pip:$PATH
```

to add it at the front. (If it's not frequently used, and doesn't need to override system commands, maybe add to the end instead.)

Many guidelines add `export PATH` but this is normally unnecessary, as the system startup files will already have declared this particular variable to be exported.

This is an extremely basic and very frequently asked question.

Comment: Okay, got it! export PATH=/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:$PATH

Comment: Right, except like I said, the `export` is completely useless.